# How to handle time outs in WSO2 ESB 4.9.0

Tags: wso2-esb

We are facing out of memory issues when lot of time outs happens with our back end service. Our application processes more than 300K transactions every day and some of our back end service times out when load is at it's peak. In this case, we have custom fault sequence initialized on API and custom fault sequence has respond mediator at the end to return the failed response to the client in case any time outs happens.

Our servers are going down and the heap dumps are pointing custom fault sequence.

Does anybody encountered this issue and also suggest us about best practices to implement custom fault sequence.

Comment: If u backend server not able to handle all requests at peak, queue of request in esb. getting bigger and esb have to hold them in memory. U can set endpoint timeout less time and retry count to one, so esb will send fault responses much faster. Provide more memory to jvm. There is also performance tips in documentation.

Comment: HI Simar, looks like in our case, WSO2 ESB is taking around 10seconds to invoke fault sequence from the main sequence in case of any time outs on end points